# How do I calculate the sum and the average of all values in a python dict by key name?

Tags: python, dictionary, sum, average, key-value

I have a `dict` object from which I want to calculate the **sum** and the **mean** of specific named `values`.

**Setup:**

```py
tree_str = """{
    'trees': [
        {
            'tree_idx': 0,
            'dimensions': (1120, 640),
            'branches': [
                'leaves': [
                    {'geometry': [[0.190673828125, 0.0859375], [0.74609375, 0.1181640625]]},
                    {'geometry': [[0.1171875, 0.1162109375], [0.8076171875, 0.15625]]}
                ],
                'leaves': [
                    {'geometry': [[0.2197265625, 0.1552734375], [0.7119140625, 0.1943359375]]},
                    {'geometry': [[0.2060546875, 0.1923828125], [0.730712890625, 0.23046875]]}
                ]
            ]
        }
    ]
}"""

tree_dict = yaml.load(tree_str, Loader=yaml.Loader)
```

**Where:**

```
# assume for the sake of coding
{'geometry': ((xmin, ymin), (xmax, ymax))}
# where dimensions are relative to an image of a tree
```

Now I have the `dict` object, how do I:

1. get the `count` of all leaves?
2. get the `average width` and `average height` all leaves?

I can access values and traverse the tree using:

```
tree_dict['trees'][0]['branches'][0]['leaves'][0]['geometry'][1][1]
```

So I could do this using nested for loops:

```py
leafcount = 0
leafwidth = 0
leafheight = 0
sumleafwidth = 0
sumleafheight = 0
avgleafwidth = 0
avgleafheight = 0

for tree in tree_dict['trees']:
    print("TREE")
    for branch in  tree['branches']:
        print("\tBRANCH")
        for leaf in branch['leaves']:
            leafcount += 1
            (lxmin, lymin), (lxmax, lymax) = leaf['geometry']
            leafwidth = lxmax - lxmin
            leafheight = lymax - lymin
            print("\t\tLEAF: x1({}), y1({}), x2({}), y2({})\n\t\t\tWIDTH: {}\n\t\t\tHEIGHT: {}".format(lxmin, lymin, lxmax, lymax, leafwidth, leafheight))
            sumleafwidth += lxmax - lxmin
            sumleafheight += lymax - lymin

avgleafwidth = sumleafwidth / leafcount
avgleafheight = sumleafheight / leafcount

print("LEAVES\n\tCOUNT: {}\n\tAVERAGE WIDTH: {}\n\tAVERAGE HEIGHT: {}".format(leafcount, avgleafwidth, avgleafheight))
```

**But is there a better way?**

```py
# psuedo code
leafcount = count(tree_dict['trees'][*]['branches'][*]['leaves'][*])
leaves = (tree_dict['trees'][*]['branches'][*]['leaves'][*])
sumleafwidth = sum(leaves[*]['geometry'][1][*]-leaves[*]['geometry'][0][*])
sumleafheight = sum(leaves[*]['geometry'][*][1]-leaves[*]['geometry'][*][0])
avgleafwidth = sumleafwidth / leafcount
avgleafheight = sumleafheight / leafcount
```

Comment: Here's something that should fit the 2nd line of your pseudo-code: `leaves = [leaf for tree in tree-dict['trees'] for branch in tree['branches'] for leaf in branch['leaves']]` ; and of course `leafcount = len(leaves)`

Comment: This question is being used as a 'known good' audit item, but it is actually currently off-topic because it asks multiple questions, one of which is opinion-based. Please edit your question to ask only one thing, and make sure it can be objectively answered. If you have your own working solution, please post it as an _answer_ instead of adding it to the question. Questions asking opinion-based things like "is there a better way" are off-topic.

Answer (score 2):

I think  that even though python dict can be used as tree representation in most cases, if you want to work with even a little more advanced tree-related tasks, as mentioned above it is not the best data structure to use.
There is a lot of implementations of tree-like structures in python, e.g. [treelib](https://treelib.readthedocs.io).
You can move from dict to Tree e.g. like that:

```
def dict_to_tree(data, parent_node=None, tree=None):
    if tree is None:
        tree = Tree()
    
    for key, value in data.items():
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            # Create a node for the key
            tree.create_node(tag=key, identifier=key, parent=parent_node)
            # Recursively call the function to process the sub-dictionary
            dict_to_tree(value, parent_node=key, tree=tree)
        else:
            # Create a node for the key and value
            tree.create_node(tag=f"{key}: {value}", identifier=key, parent=parent_node)

    return tree
```

You should be able to resolve your problems in much easier and elegant way on the correct data structure.

Answer (score 2):

Probably not the answer you expect but if you are comfortable with data analysis, you can use `pandas` and `numpy` to reshape your dataset.

```
# pip install pandas
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Build trees
branches = pd.json_normalize(tree_dict['trees'], 'branches', 'tree_idx')
leaves = pd.json_normalize(branches.pop('leaves')).melt(var_name='branch_idx', value_name='geometry', ignore_index=False)
trees = leaves.merge(branches, left_on='branch_idx', right_index=True)

# Extract geometry
geom = np.concatenate(trees.pop('geometry').str['geometry'].values).reshape(4, -1)
geom = pd.DataFrame(geom, columns=['x1', 'y1', 'x2', 'y2'], index=leaves.index)
trees = pd.concat([trees, geom], axis=1).sort_index().reset_index(names='leaf_idx')

# Width and Height
trees['width'] = trees['x2'] - trees['x1']
trees['height'] = trees['y2'] - trees['y1']
```

The output will be:

```
>>> trees
   leaf_idx  branch_idx tree_idx        x1        y1        x2        y2     width    height
0         0           0        0  0.190674  0.085938  0.746094  0.118164  0.555420  0.032227
1         0           1        0  0.117188  0.116211  0.807617  0.156250  0.690430  0.040039
2         1           0        0  0.219727  0.155273  0.711914  0.194336  0.492188  0.039062
3         1           1        0  0.206055  0.192383  0.730713  0.230469  0.524658  0.038086
```

Other usage:

```
# Average width
>>> trees['width'].mean()
0.565673828125

# Average height
>>> trees['height'].mean()
0.037353515625

# How many trees?
>>> trees['tree_idx'].nunique()
1

# How many branches?
>>> trees['branch_idx'].nunique()
2

# How many leaves?
>>> len(trees)
4
```

Comment: Yours is a good answer, though it may be overkill for my purposes and I don't fully understand it yet.

Comment: @skeetastax. That's why I said if you are comfortable with data analysis :-). If your tree is huge using Pandas can be a good alternative to vectorize the computations.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, here's another answer; though it's not strictly necessary, I make use of numpy's vectorization to sum the widths and heights of the leaves at the same time:

```
import numpy as np

leaves = [leaf for tree in tree_dict['trees'] for branch in tree['branches'] for leaf in branch['leaves']]
leafsums = sum(np.array(leaf['geometry'][1]) - np.array(leaf['geometry'][0]) for leaf in leaves)

print(f"LEAVES\n\tCOUNT: {len(leaves)}\n\tAVERAGE WIDTH: {leafsums[0]/len(leaves)}\n\tAVERAGE HEIGHT: {leafsums[1]/len(leaves)}")
```